# React-Select filter not working on react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to get question filtering to work on my react app. The issue I am encountering the issue that the questions do not filter out. For example when I click the first question from the first box, the second box does not filter out the question. It seems something is wrong with the state but I am not entirely sure because the state seems to be set fine in the hook.

As seen in the image the question should be filtered out but it isn't
[image]

Code

```js
    const [questionVals, setQuestionVals] = useState([{value: "", label: "Choose..."}, {value: "", label: "Choose..."}, {value: "", label: "Choose..."}])
    const [securityQuestions, setSecurityQuestions] = useState([{ value: "favoriteBook", label: "What is your favorite book?" }, 
                                        { value: "roadYouGrewUpOn", label: "What is the name of the road you grew up on?"},
                                        { value: "motherMaidenName", label: "What is your mother’s maiden name?" },
                                        { value: "nameOfPet", label: "What was the name of your first/current/favorite pet?"},
                                        { value: "firstCompany", label: "What was the first company that you worked for?"},
                                        { value: "meetSpouse", label: "Where did you meet your spouse?" },
                                        { value: "highSchoolCollege", label: "Where did you go to high school/college?" },
                                        { value: "favoriteFood", label: "What is your favorite food?" },
                                        { value: "cityBorn", label: "What city were you born in?" },
                                        { value: "vacationPlace", label: "Where is your favorite place to vacation?" }])
                                        
    const [availableOptions, setAvailableOptions] = useState([{ value: "favoriteBook", label: "What is your favorite book?" }, 
                                        { value: "roadYouGrewUpOn", label: "What is the name of the road you grew up on?"},
                                        { value: "motherMaidenName", label: "What is your mother’s maiden name?" },
                                        { value: "nameOfPet", label: "What was the name of your first/current/favorite pet?"},
                                        { value: "firstCompany", label: "What was the first company that you worked for?"},
                                        { value: "meetSpouse", label: "Where did you meet your spouse?" },
                                        { value: "highSchoolCollege", label: "Where did you go to high school/college?" },
                                        { value: "favoriteFood", label: "What is your favorite food?" },
                                        { value: "cityBorn", label: "What city were you born in?" },
                                        { value: "vacationPlace", label: "Where is your favorite place to vacation?" }])


    const handleQuestionValChange = (option, index) => {
        const newQuestionVals = questionVals
        newQuestionVals[index] = option

        setQuestionVals(newQuestionVals)
        getAvailableOptions()
        console.log(newQuestionVals)
    }

    const getAvailableOptions = () => {
        const availableOptionsLeft = securityQuestions
        const newOptions = availableOptionsLeft.filter(questionOption => {
            return questionVals.indexOf(questionOption) === -1
        })
        console.log(newOptions)

        setAvailableOptions(newOptions)
    }

<Form.Label htmlFor="question1">Question 1</Form.Label>
                        <Select
                            name = "filters"
                            placeholder = "Choose..."
                            value={questionVals[0]}
                            options= {availableOptions}
                            onChange={(e) => handleQuestionValChange(e, 0)}
                            required
                        >
            
                        </Select> 

                        <div class="mt-3"></div>
                        <Form.Control required id="securityQuestionOne" type="securityQuestionOne" name="securityQuestionOne" placeholder="Type your answer here" onChange={(e)=>{setSecurityQuestionOneAnswer(e.target.value)}} onKeyUp={changeButtonColor} ></Form.Control>
                        <div class="mt-3"></div>

                        <Form.Label htmlFor="question2">Question 2</Form.Label>
                        <Select
                            name = "filters"
                            placeholder = "Choose..."
                            value={questionVals[1]}
                            options= {availableOptions}
                            onChange={(e) => handleQuestionValChange(e, 1)}
                            required
                        >
                        </Select>  

                        <div class="mt-3"></div>
                        <Form.Control required id="securityQuestionTwo" type="securityQuestionTwo" name="securityQuestionTwo" placeholder="Type your answer here" onChange={(e)=>{setSecurityQuestionTwoAnswer(e.target.value)}} onKeyUp={changeButtonColor} ></Form.Control>
                        <div class = "mt-3"></div>

                        <Form.Label htmlFor="question3">Question 3</Form.Label>
                        <Select
                            name = "filters"
                            placeholder = "Choose..."
                            value={questionVals[2]}
                            options= {availableOptions}
                            onChange={(e) => handleQuestionValChange(e, 2)}
                            
                            required
                        >
            
                        </Select> 
                        <div class="mt-3"></div>
                        <Form.Control required id="securityQuestionThree" type="securityQuestionThree" name="securityQuestionThree" placeholder="Type your answer here" onChange={(e)=>{setSecurityQuestionThreeAnswer(e.target.value)}} onKeyUp={changeButtonColor} ></Form.Control>


                        <div class="mt-5"></div>
                        {error && 
                            error.map((err, i) =>
                                <Alert className="mt-3" variant='danger' key={i}>{err}</Alert>
                            )
                        }
                        <Button size="lg" className="w-100 mb-3" type="submit" ref={signupButtonRef}>{t('signup')}</Button>
                    </Form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `getAvailableOptions`, the `indexOf` you are using results in performing a [Strict Equality Comparison](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) on objects, thus comparing by reference. Since your values come from two different arrays that were instantiated separately, the references will be different for an identical question.

A possible solution is to use `find` instead and to compare using the question's `value`:

```
const newOptions = availableOptionsLeft.filter(questionOption => {
  return questionVals.find(
    question => question.value === questionOption.value
  ) === undefined;
})
```